Largest collection of subsets of [1,n] such that any union of two subsets is unique
Let $S$ be the set of integers from 1 to $n$. Then there are $2^n$ subsets of $S$. My question is what is the size of the largest collection, $F$, of these subsets such that the union of any distinct $X,Y\in F$ is unique. So given any set, $T$, that is the union of two sets in $F$, those two sets should be uniquely determined by $T$.
$F$ has $|F|\choose 2$ sets that are the union of two sets in $F$ and each are unique. This means $|F|\choose 2$$\leq 2^n$, so $|F|\leq\lceil 2^{\frac{n+1}{2}}\rceil$. On the other hand, if we take $F$ to be the collection of sets with one element as well as the empty set, we get that $|F|\geq n+1$. I am not sure how to proceed to find better bounds.
Edit: In P Erdös, P Frankl, Z Füredi's paper, 'Families of finite sets in which no set is covered by the union of two others', https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0097316582900048?ref=pdf_download&fr=RR-2&rr=889623b298c079c3, they look at the size of the largest collection of subsets, $F$, of an $n$ element set such that for any distinct $A,B,C \in F$, $A\notin B\cup C$. They find a lower bound of $1.134^n$. If $A,B,C,D\in F$ are such that $A\neq B$, $C\neq D$, {$A,B$}$\neq${$C,D$} and $A\cup B=C\cup D$ then $A\in C\cup D$ and $B\in C\cup D$. As either $A,C,D$ or $B,C,D$ are all distinct, this is a contradiction. So any $F$ that satisfies the condition in the paper also satisfies our condition. Therefore $|F|\geq 1.134^n$.

Have you computed the max for various small $n$?  Also, I'm not entirely clear of the rules.  For $n=2$, say, would ${1}, {1,2}$ be a good collection?  The point being:  the union of ${1,2}$ with itself is the same as the union of the two sets...is that allowed?

Also, to clarify:  I assume you meant to refer to the size of a maximal collection.  I wouldn't imagine that there is a unique maximal collection.

@lulu The question specifies distinct $X,Y\in F$.

https://oeis.org/A054961

@lulu Yes that would be a good set, X union X is not considered. However {1,2}, {1}, {2} would not be a good set as the union of {1,2} with {1} is the same as the union of {1,2} with {2}.

@RobPratt Thank you for the oeis link, I had not seen it.
